# substring match on both tables of a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, substring

How can I perform joins on a substring match to another substring. I seem to only be able to `ilike` search on one or the other, not substring search both.

Given tables:

**DIALOG**

```
string             
-------------------
Hi, my name is dan
```

**STRUCTURES**

```
structure
----------
his name is / my name is
hello, my / you are
how are you?
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
string              | structure
-------------------------------
Hi, my name is dan  | his name is / my name is
```

**Attempts:**

Two `ilike` fuzzy matches:

```
select string, structure from dialog left join structures on ('%' || string || '%' ilike '%' || structure || '%');
```

Two fuzzy `ilike` matches with `OR`:

```
select string, structure from dialog left join structures on (string ilike '%' || structure || '%') or (structure ilike '%' || string || '%');
```

Both output:

```
string              | structure
-------------------------------
Hi, my name is dan  |
```

Comment: `his name is / my name is` <-- this isn't normalized data, and it will make an already hard problem harder.

Comment: To emphasize Tim's comment, "his name is" does not match "my name is", so you cannot do the match.  Period.  You need to think harder about your data and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If the structures actually matches, you could use regular expressions:

```
select string, structure
from dialog d left join
     structures s
     on string ~ replace(string, ' / ', '|');
```

Of course, this doesn't work on the sample data, because the strings don't actually match.

This also suggests that your structure should actually be a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a cartesian product first, limited with a WHERE clause, to see what kind of results you can expect.

```
select string, structure from dialog CROSS join structures WHERE string ilike '%' || structure || '%' AND structure ilike '%' || string || '%'
```

I think your left join attempt does not match anything because there's wildcards on the left side of the ILIKE statement. These are, afaik, taken literally. Also, use 'AND' for the join: you want the couples where both of the predicates are true. The cross join fits OK here, as you define your where clause pretty tightly.

The left join would only be used where you want to absolutely get your 'dialog', with optionally 'structure' connected to it. In this case, do the 'full join', so you can see exactly what kind of matches are made. Later on, you can decide to further filter everything out and put the where clause predicates in suitable join clause.